# Difference between spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-web-services and spring-boot-starter-jersey

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-ws

What is the difference between:

- `spring-boot-starter-web`
- `spring-boot-starter-web-services`
- `spring-boot-starter-jersey`?

The documentation says Starter for building RESTful web applications using JAX-RS and Jersey. An alternative to `spring-boot-starter-web`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

- [spring-boot-starter-web](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.0.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-2.0.4.RELEASE.pom) -> Services on Tomcat - typically REST services using Spring MVC for web layer
- [spring-boot-starter-jersey](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jersey/2.0.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jersey-2.0.4.RELEASE.pom) -> Services on Tomcat - typically REST services using Jersey implementation of JAX-RS for web layer
- [spring-boot-starter-web-services](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web-services/2.0.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-services-2.0.4.RELEASE.pom) -> SOAP services

I highly recommend inspecting these POMs if you are familiar with Maven. Code answers your questions better than thousand SO answers.

Comment: Could you go further pls? What means using `spring-boot-starter-web` instead of `spring-boot-starter-jersey`? Advantages disadvantages?